# Making a new streaming source in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm interested in using PySpark for a real-time streaming application, but am having difficulty figuring out how to get my data stream into Spark... The data arrives via the MQTT protocol, for which there exist Python clients. Ideally I'd like to use a number of instances of these clients (each of which implement, say, an iterator interface) to stream data into Spark somehow.

Is this kind of thing possible? Any pointers on how to make a new streaming source? I'm a little confused at the moment since it seems like all the existing supported streaming sources are wrappers around Java code, whereas I'd prefer to stay in Python.

Comment: a) Not really b) Apache Bahir has MQTT source with both structured streaming and legacy streaming support for PySpark.

Comment: Pyspark **is also** a wrapper around JVM code. Whatever wrappers you've found could in theory be imported by pyspark

Comment: @cricket_007 I know, but the question is how!

Comment: @user6910411 Thanks for the pointer! I'll see where that takes me...